# Replace Windows with Opensuse on a dual-booted device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I have a dual-booted (Windows & Ubuntu 13.04) computer.

Now, after using Ubuntu for quite a long time, I am planning to switch to a solely Linux setup.

I want to remove Windows & install Opensuse OS in its place, but I don't want to harm any data in Ubuntu 13.04 as it's my primary OS.

Here's the partition table:

[image: partition table]

Can I simply delete the Windows partition & install the other Linux OS in its place?

I am asking this because, in my partition table, it shows Windows(Loader); if I do what I mentioned, is there any chance of not booting into the OS at all?
I don't want to setup my Ubuntu OS again.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Opensuse live cd, do a os-prober in terminal to see if all operating systems are listed.

1. If yes, then you are safe. Just select manual partitioning scheme,then select the windows partition, format it and install Opensuse there. Install the bootloader in the harddrive, not in any partition.
2. if it doesn't detect any 1 operating system, then there is a conflict in UEFI/EFI/Legacy bootloader. Probably opensuse is reading the UEFI BIOS, while  previous operating systems are installed in LEGACY bios. A Simple solution to this problem is to just turnoff the UEFI bios & then simply follow step 1.

Enjoy :)